# Making the same bevel object

Tags: modeling

[image]

Currently having hard time trying to figure how to add that same bevel object on the edge where the object bevel to the right and to the left can anyone tell me how to make an object on the edge and to bevel them so it can face right and left ?

here is the example of what i mean :
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it would be easier to begin with a cube, select its top face, move it down, scale it down, create an horizontal loopcut, scale it up, move it a bit up, bevel with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, choose the number of segment with the middle mouse or in the *Operator* box:

[image]

Comment: can i know before making that thing do we need to loop cut and place the cut on the half of the cube than start bevel all the edges ?

Comment: it's not exactly place on the half, it really depends on the profile you want to get

Comment: can u show me the tutorial from the 1st step ? i dont kinda understand how to get to the position u're making rn.

Comment: I've edited, I hope it helps

Comment: THANKSSS really help me for a Learner Thanks alot blender Guru